# get meta value by category AND meta value

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, metadata

Okay, so I need to write a database query to get the meta_value out of `key b`, based on the value of `key_a` and `category`.

Here's my sql:

```
        $cat   = $post['cat'];
        $adh   = $post['adhesion'];
        //get adhesions for category
        $query = $wpdb->get_results(
            "SELECT p.`ID`, pm.`meta_value` FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} `p` ON `p`.`ID` = pm.`post_id`
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} `tr` ON `p`.`ID` = `tr`.`object_id`
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} `tt` ON `tr`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `tt`.`term_taxonomy_id`
            WHERE `pm`.`meta_key` = 'substrate_box'
            AND `pm`.`meta_key` = 'adhesion_box'
            AND `pm`.`meta_value` = '$adh'
            AND `p`.`post_status` = 'publish'
            AND `p`.`post_type` = 'post'
            AND `tt`.`taxonomy` = 'category'
            AND `tt`.`term_id` = $cat
            ");
```

What I need to do is get the value of the meta_key `substrate_box` for every post that has BOTH the category value AND the first meta key value (`adhesion_box`).

This sql statement returns null, so I'm not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that ended up working, forgive its ugliness:

```
$cat   = $post['cat'];
        $adh   = $post['adhesion'];
        //get adhesions for category
                $query   = $wpdb->get_results("
                                        SELECT pm.`post_id` FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} `p` ON `p`.`ID` = pm.`post_id`
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} `tr` ON `p`.`ID` = `tr`.`object_id`
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} `tt` ON `tr`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `tt`.`term_taxonomy_id`
            WHERE `pm`.`meta_key` = 'adhesion_box'
            AND `pm`.`meta_value` = '$adh'
            AND `p`.`post_status` = 'publish'
            AND `p`.`post_type` = 'post'
            AND `tt`.`taxonomy` = 'category'
            AND `tt`.`term_id` = $cat
                        ");
    if(is_array($query)){
        foreach($query as $obj){
            $tmps = $wpdb->get_results("
                    SELECT p.`ID` as post_id, pm.`meta_value` FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
                     LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} `p` ON `p`.`ID` = pm.`post_id`
                      WHERE pm.`post_id` = {$obj->post_id}
                          AND pm.`meta_key` = 'substrate_box'
            ");
            if(is_array($tmps) && count($tmps) > 0){
                foreach($tmps as $tmp){
                    $return[$tmp->post_id] = $tmp->meta_value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This selects and returns a second meta value based on the post category and the first meta value.

Answer (score 0):

Move the WHERE clause conditions to ON clause.

```
SELECT p.`ID`, pm.`meta_value` FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} `p` ON `p`.`ID` = pm.`post_id`
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} `tr` ON `p`.`ID` = `tr`.`object_id`
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} `tt` ON `tr`.`term_taxonomy_id` = `tt`.`term_taxonomy_id`
            AND  `pm`.`meta_key` = 'substrate_box'
            AND `pm`.`meta_key` = 'adhesion_box'
            AND `pm`.`meta_value` = '$adh'
            AND `p`.`post_status` = 'publish'
            AND `p`.`post_type` = 'post'
            AND `tt`.`taxonomy` = 'category'
            AND `tt`.`term_id` = $cat
```

Comment: It should be `AND` instead of double `ON`

Comment: This dumps a whole lot of stuff, and none of it is the right meta data. This pulls all kinds of things like the site title and all that, but doesn't grab any info form the `meta_key` "substrate_box".

Comment: @RemySheppard, probably give sample data from these tables and expected output, that would be easier to understand the relations between tables.